# Start android app from embedded browser

Tags: android, embedded-browser

I need to start my installed application from embedded browser.

My use case is:

- Settings -> Accounts -> Add account -> Google -> Existing -> *menu* Browser sign-in
- after entering e-mail, user is redirected to our Shibboleth page where chooses server
- after that, our authentization app should start (automatically (the best) or via clicking the button)

What is our current solution:

- our auth android app starts (after boot) own HTTP server as service which listens on port 1234
- Shibboleth page contains iframe with URL `http://localhost:1234/our/data`
- server gets this request and starts application with "our data"

Problems:

- our Shibboleth page is running on HTTPS and iframe with HTTP is blocked on Android 5 as insecure content so our app is not opened
- registering intent filter for `ourapp://our/data` does not work, embedded browser tries to open this as common web page
- we cannot use push notifications (not our decision)

Is there any other way how to start our application from embedded browser for our purpose? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what's a _Shibboleth page_?

Comment: I thought it is common name (it isn't, sorry) - "Shibboleth is a standards based, open source software package for web single sign-on across or within organizational boundaries." Just imagine common web page that is in our service and we can edit it.